# how I get in app purchase user status in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase, in-app-purchase-receipt

I have implement in app purchase in to my app and I want to get details of already purchase subscription's sku data and currant status.

with this data I want to use for proration and cancel

is there any way to find this